# How I can joint 2 cell values in Google sheet with ARRAYFORMULA

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have data in my google sheet, now I want to joint 2 cell values. I'm able to do this task with

```
CONCATENATE(A13,B13)
```

this formula, I want to join all my values in Column B with Cell A13 in Column C like in

```
            |  C     |   
-------- ---|--------|
         C2 |A13+B13 
         C3 |A13+B14
         C4 |A13+B15
Etc.....
```

I try `ARRAYFORMULA` to do this task automatically but I'm unable and got an error.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(CONCATENATE(A13,B13:B))
```

Is it possible to achieve this, hope you got my question, Thanks in advance for the help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(A13&B13:B15)
```

or with space:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(A13&" "&B13:B15)
```

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B13:B<>"", A13&" "&B13:B, ))
```